# Regex to exclude part of string on split

Tags: c#, regex

I asked a similar question a few weeks ago on how to split a string based on a specific substring. However, I now want to do something a little different. I have a line that looks like this (sorry about the formatting):

What I want to do is split this line at all the newline \r\n sequences. However, I do not want to do this if there is a PA42 after one of the PA41 lines. I want the PA41 and the PA42 line that follows it to be on the same line. I have tried using several regex expressions to no avail. The output that I am looking for will ideally look like this:

This is the regex that I am currently using, but it does not quite accomplish what I am looking for.

```
string[] p = Regex.Split(parameterList[selectedIndex], @"[\r\n]+(?=PA41)");
```

If you need any clarifications, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying a positive look-ahead, you want a negative one. (Positive insures that the pattern *does* follow, whereas negative insures *it does not*.)

```
(\\r\\n)(?!PA42)
```

Works [for me](http://regexr.com?2v277).

Comment: Thank you. For some reason when I use this expression, it is not actually splitting unless I use @"(\r\n)(?!PA42)". However then it is also splitting the \r\n into a seperate line instead of preserving them at the end of the end of the PA## line.

Comment: @almostProgramming: Are the "\r\n" characters literally a `\` then an `n` or `r`? or are they a carriage return and line feed? That will make all the difference in the pattern, but I don't know if you're showing them fort he sake of the question, or if they're characters.

Comment: They are actually carriage returns and new lines. Sorry about that, I should have made that clear in the question.

Comment: Then you can use a class `[\r\n]+` or use `(\r|\n)+` in the pattern as you want regex to mean those specific characters, not their escaped counter-parts.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you very much. I need to invest in a regex book, that's for sure.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"\\r\\n(?!PA42)");
```

This should work. It uses a negative lookahead assertion to ensure that a \r\n sequence is not followed by PA42.

**Explanation :**

```
@"
\\         # Match the character “\” literally
r          # Match the character “r” literally
\\         # Match the character “\” literally
n          # Match the character “n” literally
(?!        # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   PA42       # Match the characters “PA42” literally
)
"
```

Comment: @almostProgramming I was first! :) But it doesn't matter. Glad that your problem is solved one way or another.